# how to install opencv3.4 with gpu support and visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017, nvidia

## I want to install opencv with gpu support.

I am quite new to OpenCV and visual studio. I have spent the last 3 days trying to install opencv3.4 with gpu support with but all in vain. I have browsed tons of links and articles but i am not able to do it. This platform is my last hope. All i want is some simple steps to follow so that i can install Open CV with GPU support.

*Note - I have install visual studio 2017, nvidia cuda development toolkit 9.1 and cmake3.1*.

Comment: At StackOverflow you are supposed to show your attempt to solve the issue. Perhaps someone can help solve the problem you have and the process would be beneficial to future readers.

Comment: @drescherjm I am so frustrated with this installation right now that i am not able to show how much efforts i have put into it. But perhaps you are right. I will add errors and my steps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start CMake and select Source-Dir and Build-Dir for OpenCV (build folder must be created by you)
2. Click *Configure*
3. Select *WITH_CUDA* in the *WITH*-Register
4. Re-Configure
5. Make sure CUDA was recognized. If not this [Link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024631/cuda-9-opencv-gt-building-errors/) will help.
6. Deselect everything you don't need or supply the libs for it (e.g. Matlab, QT, OpenGL, Eigen, PNG, JPEG, etc.)
7. Configure with no errors being shown.
8. Click *Generate*
9. Open the Build-Dir and open then *OpenCV.sln*.
10. Build OpenCV in Debug and Release-Mode. (this takes quite some time!)
11. Install OpenCV by "building" the install-target
12. Set Environment-Variables to the include- and lib-folder

    Include Folder:  /build/install/include  --> OPENCV_INCLUDE

    lib-Folder:      /build/install/x64//bin  --> OPENCV_LIB
13. Add Entry to path-Variable to include the bin folder

    Bin-Folder: /build/install/x64//bin

Comment: I think I've seen someone else suggest building in Debug before Release. Can you expand on that? Why is this necessary?

Comment: I did not come across this. I think it does not matter in which order you are building the Debug and Release version.